# Customize my wordpress plugin in home page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-rss-feeds-widget/
This works fine for me. i am using WordPress 3.3.1.
Now i want my plugin to be there in the centre of my home page and not in the side widget.
How can i achieve this.?
I mean, my plugin is there in the widget list,and i can drag my plugin to the sidebar of my template in back-end
and it reflects in the front-end at right corner.
How can i get my plugin in home page at centre of the page?
Hope someone wil help me.
In other words, how can i call my customized plugin in my template file?
Thanks
Haan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a new widget position in your functions.php file and then add the code to render out the contents of that widget in the relevant template file.

So as an example. In functions.php you would find the section fo code that is registering your existing widget positions (look for `if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {` ) and register a new position below it;

```
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Home Widget Container',
        'id'   => 'home-widget',
        'description'   => 'These are widgets for the home position.',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '<div class="home-widget-header"><h2>',
        'after_title'   => '</h2></div>'
    ));
```

And then in the template file you are using for your homepage;

```
    <?php
        if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Home Widget Container')) :
            // This will include your widgets.
        endif; 
    ?>
```

Comment: Could you please provide me the name and id parameters for my plugin if my pluginname is xxx.. How to get my id for the parameter you have mentioned above?

Comment: The name and idea is nothing to do with the plugin or the widget you are dropping in.  The id is the CSS id that will be applied to the widget position that allows you to center it as per your question.  Just leave the name exactly as it is and you'll be in business :)